# How does one bind mat-toggle-button-group with an enum?

Tags: typescript, enums, angular-material

I am trying to show an Angular Material `mat-toggle-button-group` with the three options i an enum:

```
enum Method {
    Lier,
    Sleep,
    Zelf
}
```

The template file would look something like this:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group
    name="startMethod"
    [value]="Method[selectedMethod]"
    (change)="setStartMethod(group.value)"
>
    <mat-button-toggle
        *ngFor="let method of Method | enumToArray : false"
        [value]="Method[method]"
    >
        {{Method[method]}}
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Notice that I used the string value of the enum as `[value]`, since integers don't seem to work (refer to https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11251)

The function to set the `selectedMethod` property of the component looks like this:

```
setStartMethod(val: Method) {
    this.selectedMethod = val;
}
```

This won't work however, since I get a string in return and in order to set the property to a valid `Method` member, it needs to be of type `Method`.

I would ask how to convert a string back to an enum member, but it seems to me that the whole enum to string to enum thing is a little hacky and there must be a better emthod to solve this matter. Or does the bug refered to above kill the chances of solving this the proper way?

Comment: Check if it solves your problem : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-badge-on-button-toggle-whkgzr)

Comment: @Eldar it does, but it still seems like this could be done by just using the enum. It's strange that I have to transform an enum, which is a quite common type, to an array of objects.

Comment: Even if your code works i wouldn't prefer this kind of code. You can change your `enumToArray` pipe into sth like in the stackblitz example. And use `name,value` pairs. And some times enum member names are not good choise to use as display values. (Imagine have enum members consists of multiple words) And this `Method[method]` is not a good practice at all. You should avoid defining sth like `Method = Method;` in your component.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I'm trying to get rid of it and use a solution that only uses enums where possible. I will consider replacing the pipe however, thanks for that idea!